# Error Setting up MySQL database with Gov Registry 4.6.0

Tags: mysql, wso2

I am trying to setup the Gov. registry 4.6.0 with a MySQL 5.6 community edition database

I followed the setup instructions in the 4.6.0 documentation and when I start the registry with **wso2server.bat -Dsetup** option I get the following error

```
C:\Apps\wso2greg-4.6.0\bin>wso2server.bat -Dsetup
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Apps\WSO2GR~1.0\bin\..
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,979]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,982]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, amd64
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,983]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,983]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.6.0_29
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,983]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.4-b02,Sun Microsystems Inc.
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,984]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\Apps\WSO2GR~1.0\bin\..
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,984]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\Apps\WSO2GR~1.0\bin\..\tmp
[2014-03-03 13:52:57,984]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : xxxxx, en-US, America/New_York
[2014-03-03 13:52:58,056]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2014-03-03 13:52:58,063]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2014-03-03 13:52:58,079]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2014-03-03 13:52:59,096] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.Exception: Error in creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeDatabase(DefaultRealmService.java:285)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :   CREATE INDEX REG_PATH_IND_BY_PATH_VALUE USING HASH ON REG_PATH(REG_PATH_VALUE, REG_TENANT_ID)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeDatabase(DefaultRealmService.java:278)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2777)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:949)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:795)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:139)
        ... 22 more
[2014-03-03 13:53:05,444]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I can see that in the mysql database the first 3 tables (REG_CLUSTER_LOCK, REG_LOG and REG_PATH) are created as per the mysql.sql script but the CREATE INDEX statements after that are not working and throwing errors. What is the issue?

Comment: After reading many posts it seems that **Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes** is the real issue. Seems like the mysql.sql db creation script that is shipped with gov. registry 4.6.0 needs to be fixed. Can someone address this immediately please. Kind regards, Cari

Answer (score 2):

I guess same issue has been mentioned in the [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-887). Workaround that, they have mentioned is

`This occurs when an encoding like UTF-8 is used, because it takes more than 1 byte to represent a character. When an encoding like latin1 is used, this exception does not occur.`

You can try it and check

Comment: Thanks. I created the database with latin1 as the character set and did not get any errors so that is the workaround I got.